# Why is OpenCV function that uses TBB much faster than a Boost-based implementation?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, boost

I tried to convert the example [given here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#howtoscanimagesopencv) to a multithreaded version with [Boost threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread.html).

Why is it the OpenCV LUT function more than **two times** faster than my Boost implementation?

I am able to beat the C implementation, but not the TBB version (LUT). I don't understand why. Mine is a 4 core laptop. 
In their example, they have shown that OpenCV LUT function is the fastest. LUT uses [Intel TBB](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/).

Here is the section that measures performance and launches Boost threads.

```
t = (double)getTickCount();
_global_I = I.clone();

int channels = _global_I.channels();
int nRows = _global_I.rows;
_global_NCOLS = _global_I.cols * channels;

CV_Assert(_global_I.isContinuous());
_global_NCOLS *= nRows;

for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i)
{
    NTHREADS = 4; //number of threads
    boost::thread_group tgroup;
    for(int i=0;i<NTHREADS;i++)
    {
        tgroup.create_thread(boost::bind(ScanImageAndReduceBoost,i));
    }
    tgroup.join_all();
}

t = 1000*((double)getTickCount() - t)/getTickFrequency();
t /= times;

cout << "Time of reducing with Boost (averaged for "
     << times << " runs): " << t << " milliseconds."<< endl;
```

Here is the function that does the mapping:

```
void ScanImageAndReduceBoost(int start)
{
    int i=0;
    uchar* p;
    p = _global_I.ptr<uchar>(i);

    for ( int j = start; j < _global_NCOLS; j=j + NTHREADS)
    {
        p[j] = _global_table[p[j]];
    }
}
```

`_global_I` and `_global_table` are global variables representing the image and lookup table (as in the example).

Output, averaged for 100 runs:

- runtime with the C operator `[]`: 4.65387 milliseconds.
- runtime with the LUT function: 0.79165 milliseconds.
- runtime with Boost: 1.99125 milliseconds.

Comment: Did you manage to gather more information on this ? I would be interested.

Comment: @kebs sorry not yet :)

Answer (score 4):

One thing is that your time measurement includes thread creation and destruction, which is a costly operation. The TBB-based OpenCV implementation does not re-create threads each time, so the cost of thread creation is amortized over the number of times the function is invoked; it's also possible that their thread pool is initialized in advance.

Another thing is how you distribute the loop iterations across threads, with subsequent indices processed by different threads:

```
for ( int j = start; j < _global_NCOLS; j = j + NTHREADS )
{
    p[j] = _global_table[p[j]];
}
```

So thread 0 processes `p[0]`, `p[4]` etc.; thread 1 processes `p[1]`, `p[5]` etc.; and so on. It might lead to cache conflicts, as subsequent elements occupying the same cache line are processed by different threads (it's called false sharing). Instead, try to split the overall job into bigger chunks to avoid false sharing, e.g.:

```
int chunk_size = _global_NCOLS / NTHREADS;
for ( int j = start*chunk_size; j < (start+1)*chunk_size; ++j )
{
    p[j] = _global_table[p[j]];
}
// deal with tail iterations if any
if ( start < _global_NCOLS % NTHREADS ) {
    uchar& c = p[chunk_size*NTHREADS+start];
    c = _global_table[c];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the PC I worked on now. In most parallel computation implementations I have see, they used interleaved format ie. thread 0 works on p[0] and [p4], thread 1 works on p[1] and p[5] and so on, although I am not very sure why this wouldnt lead to cache problems. Maybe L1 is separate for each core?

Comment: My guess is that this "interleaved partitioning" is just much easier to implement, comparing even to the equal-size splitting like I suggested, and thus developers without much experience in parallel programming may tend to use it.